# MySQL Command Joining

Tags: mysql

I store a list of events in a DB and a list of teams in the same DB just a different table.

**info_events**

eventid | starttime | hometeam | awayteam

**info_teams**

teamid | teamname

In the info_events table, hometeam and awayteam are both foreign keys to the teamid table.

```
  SELECT 
      info_events.eventid,  
      info_events.eventdate, 
      info_events.hometeam, 
      info_events.awayteam, 
      info_team.teamname
    FROM 
      info_events 
    INNER JOIN 
      info_teams 
    ON 
      info_events.hometeam = info_teams.teamid
```

This is my current command and works, getting the hometeam. How do I also get the away team name in the same command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `info_events` table twice, this requires unique alias name for the tables.

```
select
ie.eventid,
ie.starttime,
t1.teamname as hometeam,
t2.teamname as awayteam
from info_events ie
join info_teams t1 on t1.teamid = ie.hometeam
join info_teams t2 on t2.teamid = ie.awayteam
```

If some of the events may not have data into the info_teams then you may use `left join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

You can join a table multiple times:

```
SELECT
    ev.event_id,
    ev.event_date,
    ...
    team1.teamname as home,
    team2.teamname as away
FROM
    info_events ev
JOIN
    info_teams t1 
ON
    ev.hometeam = t1.teamid
JOIN
    info_teams t2
ON
    ev.awaytem = t2.teamid
```